# CPI Communication in IBM I (AS400)

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

Recently I came across a thing called CPI Communication (common programming interphase) in one of a rpgle program I was working on. Instead of calling other programs directly they are using something called CPI for making the same call. I was just told that is a more efficient way of calling than a normal call.
Can someone kindly explain in simpler terms what is the difference between CPI and a normal static or dynamic call?

Answer (score 1):

[check out this link](https://www.mcpressonline.com/programming/apis/programming-with-the-cpic-api)

( I have removed the rest of my answer as it was wrong. )

Comment: Based on your link, it looks like CPI-C is a client-server communication method. The server program must be running and waiting for a connection request. In addition the server program is running in a different process from the requestor. This is totally different from a dynamic or static call. In a dynamic or static call the called program does not start running until it is called, and it runs in the same job as the caller.